# WEB PUSH Notificaciones en IOS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, ios, pwa

El problema es el siguiente:

Antes de arrancar con el problema quiero aclarar que tenemos una PWA con tecnología TWA para poder subir este mismo a las tiendas (App Store y Play Store)

Tenemos una PWA y actualmente manejamos notificaciones basándose en acciones del usuario, un ejemplo es cuando compra el usuario, a él le llega un pedido de que su pago ha sido exitoso. ahora arrancando con este ejemplo, necesitamos que justo en la última etapa, cuando el usuario tenga que retirar sus productos le mande una notificación, a nivel lógico tenemos todo contemplado, pero ahora tenemos el siguiente problema.

Necesitamos que el sistema de notificaciones "WEB PUSH" funcione en IOS, ya que en andriod funciona de maravilla, pero en IOS no está funcionando. IOS todavia no lanzo al mercado una forma de conectarse y lanzar notificaciones de este modo.

La solución que se nos ocurrió fue la siguiente:
Tenemos la PWA conectada a una base de datos MongoDB donde tenemos a cada usuario que le debemos mandar notificaciones registrados. Sabemos que desde una app nativa iOS podemos hacer este tipo de cosas, pero nuestro problema es confrontar esto desde un PWA, la idea es pasar la app a nativa Swift, hacer un Webview para mostrar la aplicación y con esto nos podemos agarrar de mas funcionalidades, ya que ahora literalmente estaríamos como app nativa, hasta acá todo es color rosa, pero con esta idea tenemos un problema, como identificamos un usuario que está guardado en la base de datos y que se estaría conectando en la PWA. Necesitaríamos obtener un identificador que se comparta tanto en nativo como en PWA. y acá está el problema, no existe o no encontramos un identificador que pueda compartir el PWA y el nativo. encontramos id de la cámara, Id Mac, pero no lo sentimos estable para poder hacer este tipo de cosas.

Resumen: Necesitamos una solución para hacer WEBPUSH EN IOS DESDE PWA CON REACT o encontrar un id que se comparta en nativo como en PWA

Tecnologías que utilizamos: MERN STACK (MONGODB, EXPRESS, RECT Y NODEJS)

Comment: No entiendo tu problema con el ID, por qué desde una PWA no tienes ese problema y desde swift+WebView si lo tendrías???

Comment: Necesitas el device token de cada iPhone, almacenarlo y de acuerdo a cada acción que hace ese id envías las notificaciones push. Desde react, ionic, xamarin se puede obtener el device token agregando el código necesario en Xcode. Igual debes agregar en Xcode que el proyecto soporte notificaciones push, en el profile y en el certificado de tu cuenta de programador.